# Removing weird line breaks exported from Oracle TOAD

Tags: python, excel, oracle, toad, longtext

So I'm trying to remove weird line breaks in order to read a LONG datatype field into a single field on Excel. Length of field does not matter as long as we get all the info into a single field.

After exporting the dataset from TOAD into a .txt flat file, if I open the file on Notepad, the rows are generated perfectly. However, when I open the file on Excel, weird line breaks are inserted to generate bad rows. These line breaks originate from the LONG datatype's line breaks, but I can't figure out to remove them so that I can view the good format on Excel.

I considered loading the .txt file in Python and do a "for line in file.readline" then a "line.replace("\n","")" for all the lines, but I'm not sure if the actual character is a "\n", and whether Python would read the bad line breaks like Excel as well.

Anyways, it's not a huge issue, but wanted to see if there was a quick or interesting fix out there. I could always do my analysis on the .txt file.

[image: Picture of the bad line breaks]

Answer (score 0):

If those *line breaks* are `CHR(10)` and/or `CHR(13)`, you could replace them with an empty string in `SELECT`, e.g.

```
select replace(replace(col, chr(10), ''), chr(13), '') as result
from some_table
```